# Subsetting every other row in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a tricky issue in which I would like to, from a Pandas dataframe, subset every other column into another dataframe, and remove it from the original dataframe. Here here is an example:

```
firstname  = ['John', 'Eric', 'Sarah', 'Kate']
lastname = ['Adams', 'Firth', 'Smith', 'Johnson']
df = pd.DataFrame({"First": first, "Last":last})
```

The output I would ideally like to have would be the following: Original dataframe contains records of firstname John and Sarah, and the second would contain records of firstname Eric and Kate.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So, you want to distribute your dataframe into two?

Comment: @harvpan Essentially yes. Every other row will need to be in the second dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using, `iloc`

```
df1, df2 = df.iloc[::2,:], df.iloc[1::2,:]
```

`df1` Output:

```
    First    Last
0   John    Adams
2   Sarah   Smith
```

And, 
`df2` Output:

```
   First    Last
1   Eric    Firth
3   Kate    Johnson
```